# How can I make a condition that I give for one Row all numbers the value 100 with an apply function

Tags: r, function, apply

I have several row and columns in a data set. And my task is to change one row for each column the value to 100

and it is necessary to use an apply function with the condition just one line code

Comment: Since your question is about using `apply`, you can try this `df[3,] <- apply(df[3,], 2, function(x) 100)`. This replaces the `3`rd row with a `100`. If there are factors, this may generate `NA`'s.

Comment: Maybe you can show what the dataset is like? Quite weird to use apply for one row. the comment above by @deepseefan will work.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `[` to assign the specified row to 100

```
df[3, ] <- 100
```